# how to play Youtube Video in VLC Player

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, youtube, window

How to to play youtube Video in VLC Player. How this possible. we have windows 7 and VLC media player 2.1.3....?
like. this video play into VLC [video link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntZs3A_xnvw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the youtube link and open your VLC program and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keys and paste your link and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>